# Conditional formatting- Excel - Icon sets

Tags: excel

[image]

Hi , Anyone can tell me why when I set the rules for conditional formatting, it does not turn out as what I want ( Tick for 1 and cross for 0)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the second Edit! :)
This is what works for me:

[image]

The type is "Number", you see yourself the result.

1. Edit:
   Just saw that the solution is exactly as yours, this means that the mistake should be somewhere else, not in the conditioning.
2. Edit:
   Your problem is that you do not have exact "0", but you add a fraction of a number to them through the RAND() Formula. To see the number you are using, select it and press Ctrl+1, while selecting the cell and then icnrease the number of decimals.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below image. Hope this answers your question.

[image: Conditional formatting]